# logstash JDBC connection to DB2 failed

Tags: db2, logstash, db2-400

I want to check one of our DB2 database's table via logstash but I got this exception.

> [2018-02-06T13:34:34,175][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#, :backtrace=>["com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(com/ibm/as400/access/JDError.java:824)", "com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(com/ibm/as400/access/JDError.java:553)", "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCConnection.java:3391)", "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDriver.java:1419)", "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDriver.java:1256)", "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDriver.java:395)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)",

this is my input config

```
 input {
     beats {
        port => 5044
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
     }
     jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:as400://ip/db"
        jdbc_user => "usr"
        jdbc_password => "pass"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/lib/jt400-9.1.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM table1 FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY"
     }
 }
```

I have to mention that the firewall inside of the Database have been disabled.

Comment: I cant see the *actual* Db2-exception detail.  Which version of logstash are you using?   Have you seen https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6001 ?

Comment: I use logstash 5.1.1 and the jt400-9.1.jar

Comment: Don't know if that's what causes the exception, but your SELECT statement has incorrect syntax -- the `FETCH FIRST` clause must include the number of rows to fetch.

Comment: I solve it by replacing jt400.jar by db2jcc4.jar